# Moneymaking in Perfect World International?

Tags: perfect-world

I like to play Perfect World International, but I'm not interested in spending real money on the game.  How can I make "game money" easily without paying "real money" for it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to have a store open 24/7 you can make and sell shards for crazy stone quest. You can get a small profit of players that dont wanna spend a few min on making them thereself. Getting real rich might take time tho, since the profit is kind of small since other players doing this aswell and that couse the price to drop.

Farming is the hard workers way to get money, either farm mats from Twilight Temple and simulair instances, or farm mid/high mats out in the world. Even herbs can be sold.

If you are able to join a faction that owns some territories, and they pay thier members for doing Territory War, thats an easy way to get a weekly pay check.

Answer (score 0):

After few updates there are several ways to make money in Perfect World.

Easiest way is the Cube. It's daily event where you need to go throught 50 rooms. You need to get into room 18 or 46. You'll recieve 9 cards and you need to buy 1. There are vendors who sold (2x of buy price) and buy cards. You can sell 9 or buy 1.

Also in the cube you can buy some boxes. For example, it's event in room 8 and 17 (there are more such rooms). It depends on box, but you can get 1M (10%), 5M (2%), 3 Shards or 1 (yes, one, 90%). Sometimes it's worth opening, or you can sell and earn 10-15k.

There are clan hall evenets where you can get valuable items to sell, but I haven't been there yet.